# iOS Web App: Hover effect over border

Tags: html, css, web-applications

Alright, I am really unsure how to word my problem, so here are two screenshots which help describing my issue. The first one is from the Settings app in iOS. This is the tap behaviour I want:

[image]

Now this right here is what I have. Notice how the upper border sticks out one pixel.

[image]

I have prepared a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmmsksv9/1/) with my HTML markup and CSS.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

.group {
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.separator {
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.item:last-child .separator {
    display: none;
}

.item.active {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ntest0tb/2/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated from your edit, I think I now know what you want :)

I'm not sure if I understood your question but check it out with this CSS:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

.group {
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.separator {
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}

.item:last-child .separator {
    display: none;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
        
   <div class="item active">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I switched to :hover to better understand the effect.

Hope it's useful.